# how to install ifb module in ububtu

Tags: software-sources

When run modprobe command get error

```
 root@my-pool6:/opt/calltest#  modprobe ifb
 modprobe: FATAL: Module ifb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-107-generic
```

So I want to install the  **ifb** moudle in the ubuntu, how to install it ?
The ubuntb info:

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: What is "ifb module"?

Comment: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/ifb this is doc about it.

Comment: What is your architecture (`uname -m`)? The module (ifb.ko) appears to be available for at least amd64 - see [linux-modules-5.4.0-107-generic filelist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/linux-modules-5.4.0-107-generic/filelist)

Comment: `# uname -m
     x86_64`

Comment: it is X86_64 and it is one docker container.  @steeldriver

Comment: Ah OK so I have no experience with docker containers - but I suspect that adds a whole layer of complexity. See for example [Can I operate on Linux kernel modules / devices from within a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67625697/can-i-operate-on-linux-kernel-modules-devices-from-within-a-docker-container) and [How to load kernel modules for docker container without privileged mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491013/how-to-load-kernel-modules-for-docker-container-without-privileged-mode)